# Erro: Use the defaultValue or value props instead of setting children on <textarea>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a problem when using the  component in my React application. Whenever I try to pass a value to the  using the value property, I get the following warning in the console:

> React-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props instead of setting children on .
> at textarea

I've already tried several solutions, including changing the defaultValue property to value in the  component, but the warning persists and the value is not displayed correctly in the .

Here is the code for my  component:

```html
import { Container } from "./styles";

export function TextArea({value, ...rest}){
    return(
        <Container {...rest}>
            <textarea value={value} {...rest} />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

And here's how I'm using the  component in my edit page:

```html
import { Container, Form } from "./styles";
import { FiArrowLeft } from "react-icons/fi";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Header } from "../../components/Header";
import { Input } from "../../components/Input";
import { TextArea } from "../../components/TextArea";
import { NoteItem } from "../../components/NoteItem";
import { Section } from "../../components/Section";
import { Button } from "../../components/Button";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { api } from "../../services";

export function Update() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [rating, setRating] = useState("");
  const [descriptionObject, setDescriptionObject] = useState({});

  const [newTag, setNewTag] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchNote() {
      const response = await api.get(`/notes/${params.id}`);
      const noteData = response.data;
      setData(noteData);
      setTitle(noteData.title);
      setRating(noteData.rating);
      setDescriptionObject(noteData.description || {});
      setTags(noteData.tags || []);
      console.log(noteData);
    }

    fetchNote();
  }, [params.id]);

  function handleAddTag() {
    setTags((prevState) => [...prevState, newTag]);
    setNewTag("");
  }

  function handleRemoveTag(deleted) {
    setTags((prevState) => prevState.filter((tag) => tag !== deleted));
  }

  async function handleUpdateFilm() {
    if (!title) {
      return alert("Digite o nome do filme");
    }
    if (newTag) {
      return alert(
        "Existem tags para serem adicionados! Clique para adicionar ou deixe o campo vazio."
      );
    }

    await api.put(`/notes/${params.id}`, {
      title,
      description,
      tags,
      rating,
    });
    alert("Filme atualizado com sucesso!");
    navigate("/");
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Form>
          <header>
            <Link to="/">
              <FiArrowLeft />
              Voltar
            </Link>
            <h1>{data.title}</h1>
          </header>
          <div className="input-row">
            <Input
              placeholder="Titulo"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Input
              inputMode="numeric"
              pattern="[0-5]"
              maxLength="1"
              placeholder="Sua nota (de 0 a 5)"
              value={rating}
              onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <TextArea
            placeholder="Observações"
            value={descriptionObject.description || ""}
            onChange={(e) => setDescriptionObject({...descriptionObject, description: e.target.value})}
          />
          <Section title="Marcadores" />
          <div className="mark-row">
            {tags.map((tag, index) => (
              <NoteItem
                key={String(index)}
                value={tag}
                onClick={() => {
                  handleRemoveTag(tag);
                }}
              />
            ))}
            <NoteItem
              isNew
              placeholder="Novo Marcador"
              onChange={(e) => setNewTag(e.target.value)}
              value={newTag}
              onClick={handleAddTag}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="button-row">
            <Button className="deleteFilm" title="Excluir Filme" />
            <Button
              title="Salvar Alterações"
              onClick={handleUpdateFilm}
            />
          </div>
        </Form>
      </main>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I would like to know how I can fix this warning and make the value display correctly in the .

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use **placeholder Attribute**, which doesn't add a value but might be what you are looking out for :

```
<textarea placeholder="this text will show in the textarea"></textarea>
```

Check it out here - `http://jsfiddle.net/8DzCE/949/`